# Discard curl downloads below a minimum file size

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I regularly need to iterate through some image downloads via `curl` and want to discard those downloads that are below a certain file size, because they obviously don't exist, i. e. the returned "image" is a 404 page. `curl` has a `--max-filesize` option, but not one for minimum file sizes.

I was thinking of something where I would pass the URL image location and the minimum file size to the script `curlmin`, such as

> curlmin url minfilesize

I believe that since I'm using sequences of alphanumeric series using [ ] to iterate through days, I need to be able to delete those files below a certain file size "on the fly". My attempt below is anything but complete, because I'm stuck on how to reference the "current" file in the 'if' statement and how to actually delete the file. But it might as well be that my one liner wouldn't work in first place either.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -O $1 | if [ $(wc -c <"$1") -le $2 ]; then delete_file_here; fi
                            ^^                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Is `curl` the only option you've got? Why not `wget`?

Comment: I only have curl installed. Is `wget` better suited for these things? I was under the impression that `curl` is "a more modern" approach (without defining "modern" really...), better updated and more widely used these days.

Comment: `wget` is more suited to your use-case which is `download the files that do exist`.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I should have a look to install `wget` then...

Comment: I hadn't really paid attention to you're trying to avoid creating files when the remote one doesn't exist.  Just use `-f` to your `curl` command.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want `curl` to avoid creating a local file when the remote one doesn't exist or there was an error in requesting/downloading it just use the `-f` flag:

```
curl -fO "$1"
```

If, however, you want to remove files below a certain size, here are a couple of options:

You can get the filename by using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to get rid of everything up to the last `/` like `${1##*/}`

so you could do

```
curl -O "$1"
if [[ $(wc -c < "${1##*/}") -le $2 ]]; then
    rm -f "${1##*/}"
fi
```

or we could check using `find`:

```
curl -O "$1"
find . -type f -name "${1##*/}" -size -"$2"c -delete
```

assuming your `find` supports `-delete`.  Otherwise you could replace that with `-exec rm -f {} +`

and if your `curl` command might download multiple files you can easily adapt the `find` command to find all files in a directory structure smaller than the given size.

The safest path is to use `find` since it won't be tripped up by strange filenames.  Failing that, you could try using another language that is better able to support these operations.  If you are confident that you have only safe names you could try the following:

```
curl -O "$1" 2>&1 | awk -v min_size="$2" '/-->/ {"stat -c%s " $NF | getline s; if(s < min_size) {system("rm " $NF);}}'
```

which will pass `$2` into `awk` as the variable `min_size`.  Then we'll look at each line of `curl` output that contains `-->`.  The last field of those lines (assuming safe names again) is the local filename, so we'll call `stat` on that to get the size (`-c %s`) and then check if that size is below our `min_size`.  If it is, call `rm` on it, once again trusting that we have safe names and not ones that will contain `IFS` or globbing characters or the like.

Comment: It doesn't quite seem to delete "on the fly". If I try `./curlmin http://www.bom.gov.au/gms/IDE00135.201707[031630-041130].jpg 23000`, whereby 23000 is a bit more than the 22,162 bytes of an "invalid" image, then I still download all those. In this example only files ending in 031630 and 041130 are valid images.

Comment: @AlexIxeras ahh, curl seems to do globbing differently from bash so the parameter expansion isn't a) operating on one file as I first though, and b) finding the downloaded files and c) would certainly download the file before checking it size to delete it.  If you must not do c) there, you might need to switch to another language than shell, like using python to download the files if the headers checkout for your needs or something

Comment: @AlexIxeras would an acceptable solution be to download everything to a clean directory and remove the files from there that are too small?

Comment: It would be acceptable to download the files first and then delete those that are too small. Is there a way to delete a file that's too small right after it has been downloaded, or would the solution be to download all files (even when it's 1000s) and then delete all that are too small? – BTW, because of that I was thinking of piping the output as I've tried in my original post, but without knowing if that really works.

Comment: @AlexIxeras the safest path is probably to download them and use `find` so you don't have to worry about unsafe names.  If you really want to go the route of deleting as you go and are confident no one will slip in dangerous filenames for you I included a possible solution--but I really have to stress that it could be dangerous if, say, there was a file named `benign; rm -rf ~` then we'd end up executing that and deleting everything in your home directory

Comment: Thank, @Eric for the additional explanations and the curl "f"-flag, which I didn't know yet. It seems to resolve most issues, but I keep your script handy in case.

Answer (score 1):

Using `wget` along with curly brace expansion <sup><sup>[[ Check here ]](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-brace-expansion#content-header)</sup></sup> to solve the problem

```
wget http://www.bom.gov.au/gms/IDE00135.201707{031630..031637}.jpg
```

Comment: This only creates a file called `IDE00135.201707[031630-031637].jpg`, if I call `./curlmin http://www.bom.gov.au/gms/IDE00135.201707[031630-031637].jpg`. Only the file ending in 031630 is a valid image.

Comment: I overlooked the fact that there can be multiple images. Will update in a moment.

Comment: Does the command `wget http://www.bom.gov.au/gms/IDE00135.201707{031630..031637}.jpg` only download files that exist?

Comment: @AlexIxeras  Yes. It only download those file that exist.